# Plasma 5 Klipper action automatically without shortkey 'Ctrl + Alt + r '?

Tags: plasma5, klipper

I'm using KDE Plasma 5.19.5 with Kate, Dolphin & Konsole. I just tried to use Klipper's action feature.
What I've reached, is that I could chose to start mpv in combination with the highlighted mp4 video, e.g. /mnt/NAS/Filme/King_Kong.mp4 .

What works, is that after highlighting, I have to press 'Ctrl + Alt +r ' to receive a (Klipper) menue, where I can click 'Execute Play video with mpv'.

My question:

Is it possible to receive the menu without pressing 'Ctrl + Alt + r'?
In my Klipper's settings for the action to start 'mp4' files I selected 'automatic', but the menu does not appear automatically.

Thank you very much in advance,

-Linuxfluesterer

Comment: Please clarify where exactly is the "highlighting" taking place? Selection with the mouse in the file manager? the text editor or terminal? clipboard list?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the required setting is enabled:

[image]

it works like this:

- clipboard actions apply to items present in the clipboard list - that is *copied* items
- these items have to be *paths* - either paths to files and folders, or URLs
- in order to copy and send to clipboard a path without using a "copy" action, you have to enable the other option called *"keep the selection and clipboard the same"*:

[image]

Paths for file and folders have to start with `file://` (the path you get when copying a file or folder, and not just its location)

In Dolphin, copying the file should pop-up the list as long as `dolphin` is not listed in the exclusion list under *Configure clipboard (right-click the tray widget) -Action menu - Exclude windows:*

[image]

Considering text editors like Kate and terminals like Konsole, *if what you mean is having the list of clipboard actions popping up when you select the mp4 file path* in Kate or Konsole -- as said above: the path that works is the one you get when you *copy the file itself, not just its location*, something like

`file:///mnt/NAS/Filme/King_Kong.mp4`

You have to be sure that the applications involved are not in that exclusion list and that the option
*"keep the selection and clipboard the same"* is enabled as said.